# i18n model not displaying translated text

Tags: sapui5

I have i18n property to bind to the label but when I try to bind the property, it does not work.

i18n_en

```
TABLE_ItemCateg=Item Category
```

view.xml

```xml
<Label text="{i18n>TABLE_ItemCateg}" />
```

It displays `"TABLE_ItemCateg"` rather than `"Item Category"`.

And in `i18n.properties`, I have no data saved. Also I receive below error:

> could not find any translatable text for key 'TABLE_ItemCateg' in bundle '../../sap/xyz_homepage/i18n/i18n.properties'

manifest.json

```json
"models": {
  "i18n": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
    "settings": {
      "bundleName": "xyz_homepage.i18n.i18n"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: my project from the WebIDE always have a namespace and a projectname. Therfore, the bundleName inside the manifest looks like: "bundleName": "name_space.project_name.i18n.i18n"

Comment: Well am i declaring it wrongly?

Comment: "i18n.properties" is yout fallback file, always insert same i18n variables into this file.

Comment: How do you execute the different languages EN, DE, FR?

Comment: with respect to their languages. And though at the moment i have defined only languages are DE and EN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## definition

you have to add your text to all of your used translation files

**i18n.properties**

TABLE_ItemCateg=Item Category

**i18n_en.properties**

TABLE_ItemCateg=Item Category

## usage

use the appropriate model

**view.xml**

text="{i18n>TABLE_ItemCateg}"

Comment: I have added all text files to my 18n properties, but still not working. Its showing same as "TABLE_ItemCateg" as text.